# Consider the set $A = \{a,b,c\}$ with power set $P (A)$ and $\cap:P(A)\times P(A)\to P(A)$. What is its range?

Tags: functions

I have this problem about functions.

Consider the set $A = \{a,b,c\}$ with power set $P (A)$ and $\cap:P(A)\times P(A) \to P(A)$. What is its range?

Am I correct to say that $P(A)$ is the range. Is there any working that I should show? Thanks!

Comment: Well, given any subset $S$ you should give an example of two subsets with intersection $S$ (though this is not difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X\cap X=X$ for any $X\in \mathcal{P}(A)$. So, the range of the function $\cap$ is all $\mathcal{P}(A)$.